# How can make add operation for long integer in excel's cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

As we all know the below simple add operation:

```
    123456789123
    +        123
---------------------
    123456789246
```

If i type `'123456789123` in `A1` and `123` in `B1`,type `=A1+B1` in `C1` ，it can't work.
If i type  `123456789123` in `A1`,it turns into `1.23457E+11`,type `123` in `B1`,type `=A1+B1` in `C1` ,we get `1.23457E+11` in `C1`.
None of them can get the correct result,how can express the simple add operation in `EXCEL` then?

Comment: To avoid scientific notation (assuming your integers are less than 16 digits), then why not change the cell format to Number? Based on your example this would work just fine.

Comment: I got it,just convert the format for `c1`!

Comment: As isolated said, excel's default cell format is general, changing it to number solves the problem.